# Hashcat does 1-7 numeric characters on brute force attack when specifying 8

Tags: network, wpa2, hashcat

I have Hashcat 0.49 on Kali Linux 1.1.0a and I have a .hccap file. It's a WPA2 Network in the file so I chose a mask of 8 numeric characters (?d?d?d?d?d?d?d?d) and instead of starting at 8 numeric characters it does 1-7 first which takes a long time. How can I fix this?

Comment: answer found in the hashcat documentation: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the [Mask Attack](http://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=mask_attack) and not Brute-force Attack which is outdated and replaced by Mask Attack.

I had to add `--pwd-min=8` to the list of parameters to force it to start at 8 digits from the get-go.

Source: http://hashcat.net/forum/thread-1538.html

Answer (score 0):

Do you have '-i' or increment enabled? This sounds like you do. Disable it if you don't want it to run through all shorter permutations.

Comment: I don't see a -i or --increment option in the help.

Comment: Sorry I use oclhashcst, it works slightly differently, in hashcat 0.5 they brought in a feature for changing increments as it was on by default in 0.49 and earlier. I suggest that kprovost7314 should update to version 0.5 and then increment of off by default.

Comment: Please see https://hashcat.net/trac/ticket/572